# Dispatch an action without a type

Tags: redux

I want to dispatch an action

```
export const signout = () => {
  return function (dispatch)  {
    firebaseAuth.signOut()
      .then(() => dispatch(signOutSuccess()));
  };
}

export const signOutSuccess = () => {
    type: SIGN_OUT_SUCCESS
}
```

But redux-logger is freaking out because it doesn't have a type property.

```
redux-logger.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
    at redux-logger.js:1
    at redux-logger.js:1
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `signOutSuccess` does not return anything.

Try something like that

```
export const signOutSuccess = () => {
    return {type: SIGN_OUT_SUCCESS}
}
```

Or more concise:

```
export const signOutSuccess = () => ({
    type: SIGN_OUT_SUCCESS
})
```

Comment: The verbose one with `return` makes it less likely to make a mistake. Use that one.

Answer (score 2):

Seems that you're not returning an object in your `signOutSuccess()` function. You need to wrap the curly braces in parentheses.

```
export const signOutSuccess = () => ({ type: SIGN_OUT_SUCCESS });
```